# How to do submit form on accordion title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to do submit form on jQuery accordion?

I used this plugin http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

In title `<h3></h3>` i need create a form for editing the item, but when click in button to submit, nothing happens.

My code:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>    
        Accordion Title

        <!-- This post not submit when click in button "Alter" -->
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="itemId" id="itemId">
            <input type="submit" value="Alter">
        </form>
    </h3>

    <div>   
        Accordion Content   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you leave out the `action` attribute by mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a way

The code:

```
<script>
    $('#accordion h3 input[type=submit]').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>

<div id="accordion">
    <h3>    
        Accordion Title

        <!-- This post not submit when click in button "Alter" -->
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="itemId" id="itemId">
            <input type="submit" value="Alter">
        </form>
    </h3>

    <div>   
        Accordion Content   
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't said where you are posting to in the form tag.  You need an `action` attribute.  See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

e.g. `<form action="doSomething.php" method="POST">`

Comment: Hi, the action redirect for the same page, this not a problem

Comment: You have to add the action, if you omit it, nothing happens. Even if it#s the same page, you have to specify it.